# How to access the list from one method to another in the same class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the below code,  but it is giving an error :AttributeError: 'test_id' object has no attribute 'IDlist', i want to fetch random value form list in test02 method :

```
class test_id
    def test_01_ID(self):
        self.df = self.sqlObj.executequerytodataframe(self.query)
        self.myid =self.df["id"]
        self.IDlist = self.myid.values.tolist()

    @pytest.mark.dependency( depends=["test_01_ID"])
    def test_02_GetID1(self):
        random_id = random.sample(self.IDlist,1)
        print(random_id)
```

Comment: Have you called the method `test_01_ID` first? The attribute `IDlist` won't exist otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using `pytest-dependency` - otherwise, `@pytest.mark.dependency(...)` doesn't do anything.

You need to mark all tests in the dependency graph with `@pytest.mark.dependency(...)`. Including the ones that don't have any dependencies - in that case, don't pass any arguments to `dependency()`.
Also, since the first test is also in the class, you have to add the class' name to the `depends` argument: `depends=["test_id::test_01_id"]`.
Another issue is that pytest creates a new instance of the class for each test method - you have to use `test_id.IDlist` instead of `self.IDlist` to overcome that.

As a side note - if you have some initialization code that has to be run before some tests, it's better to use pytest fixtures. In this case, it would be something like this:

```
@pytest.fixture
def id_list():
    df = self.sqlObj.executequerytodataframe(self.query)
    myid = df["id"]
    return self.myid.values.tolist()

def test_GetID(id_list):
    ...
```